# Back to top not focusing on required field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a submit button in a form and have implemented jQuery back to top on it.

It works fine however when I press the submit button it just goes to top ignoring the required field attribute for one of my fields.

If I remove the backtotop id from the submit button I can see the required field error.

It just doesn't submit the form if I add backtotop id on the submit button.

**What am I missing?**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fname" required>
    <input type="submit" id="backToTop" class="button" value="Register">
</form>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#backToTop').fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            $('#backToTop').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    $('#backToTop').click(function () {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 100);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else is interfering please use a JSFiddle, probably look at your CSS.

As for your scroll to top 50, note that not all users have the same resolution. you will need to detect the increment.

```
scrollbartarget/Scrollbarheight = location
```

unless you wish to prevent the form from submitting return true inside your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return false` in the click handler will prevent the form submitting. If you want the form to submit, you must `return true;`.